# Find groups of duplicates in data frame by all columns except one

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe. For some purposes I need to do the following:

- Select one column in this data frame
- Iterate on all rows of a given data frame except selected column
- Select all rows of this data frame that are equal by all elements except one selected column
- Group them by the way that group name is the row index and group values are indexes of duplicated rows.

I have wrote a function for this task, but it works slow because of nested loop. I would like to get some ideas how this code can be improved.

Say we have a dataframe like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  1  2
2  1  2  2  1
3  1  1  1  2
4  1  1  2  1
5  2  2  1  2
```

And we want to get this list as a output:

```
diff.dataframe("V2", conf.new, conf.new)
```

Ouput:

```
$`1`
[1] 1

$`2`
[1] 2

$`3`
[1] 1 3

$`4`
[1] 2 4

$`5`
[1] 5
```

The following code reaces the goal, but it works too slow. Is it possible to improve it somehow?

```
diff.dataframe <- function(param, df1, df2){
  excl.names <- c(param)
  df1.excl <- data.frame(lapply(df1[, !names(df1) %in% excl.names], as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df2.excl <- data.frame(lapply(df2[, !names(df2) %in% excl.names], as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  list.out <- list()

  for (i in 1:nrow(df1.excl)){
     for (j in 1:nrow(df2.excl)){
        if (paste(df1.excl[i,],collapse='') == paste(df2.excl[j,], collapse='')){
          if (!as.character(i) %in% unlist(list.out)){                                                                                                                             
            list.out[[as.character(i)]] <- c(list.out[[as.character(i)]], j)                                                                                                       
          }
        }
     }
  }
  return(list.out)
}
```

Comment: I take it that your function works but you want to improve the speed, right? I can't figure out how to run it though, so it would be helpful if you could provide a small example dataset and the desired output that we can validate our solutions against. Paste the output of `dput(df1)`, `dput(df2)` and show the call to the function please.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results.

Comment: How come row 1 matches to row 3, but row 3 do not match to row 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's generate some data first

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(2, 20, TRUE), 5))

# Produces df like this
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  2  1  1  1
2  2  1  2  2
3  1  1  2  2
4  1  2  1  1
5  1  2  1  1
```

We then loop through the lines with `lapply`. Each row `i` is then compared to all lines of `df` with `apply` (including itself). The rows with <= 1 differences returns `TRUE`, the others return `FALSE` producing a logical vector, which we convert to a numeric vector with `which`.

```
lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i)
    apply(df, 1, function(x) which(sum(x != df[i,]) <= 1)))

# Produces output like this
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 4 5
```